# Load ansible vars in specific tasks

Tags: ansible

I feel I must be missing this answer as it seems obvious but I've read a number of posts and have not been able to get this working.

Currently I am loading and then templating vars from files depending on inventory hostnames, like so:

```yaml
  - name: load unique dev vars from file
    include_vars:
      file: ~/ansible/env-dev.yml
    when: inventory_hostname in groups[ 'devs' ]

  - name: load unique prod vars from file
    include_vars:
      file: ~/ansible/env-prod.yml
    when: inventory_hostname == 'prod'

  - name: copy .env dev file with templated vars
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: ~/ansible/env-dev.j2
      dest: /home/{{ inventory_hostname }}/.env
      owner: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      group: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      mode: '0600'
    when: inventory_hostname in groups[ 'devs' ]
```

This works fine but ultimately it is requiring me to create a ton of .yml files when I would rather include some variables in certain steps instead.

Is it possible to load vars for a specific task? I've tried a number of solutions but haven't been able to make it work yet. See below for one method I tried using `vars` at the end of the task.

```yaml
  - name: copy .env dev file with templated vars
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: ~/ansible/env-dev.j2
      dest: /home/{{ inventory_hostname }}/.env
      owner: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      group: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      mode: '0600'
    when: inventory_hostname in groups[ 'devs' ]
    vars:
       NODE_ENV: development
       PORT: 66
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to organize your Ansible code is to rely on [group vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables).

This feature permits to load variables according to the group a host belong to. You have several ways to do that, one of the clearest way is to use `yaml` files named with the name of the group in the `group_vars` folder (plus a `all.yaml` matching all hosts). Ansible will pick automatically them for you, so you can get rid of your first two `include_vars`. You can combine them with variables specific to the role and or the playbook. So you end with a set of variables coming from the host (the target) and from the role / playbook (the task to achieve).

To replace the hardcoded `src: ~/ansible/env-dev.j2` you could for example define a variable in each group.

```yaml
---
# dev.yaml
template_name: "env-dev.j2"
---
# prod.yaml
template_name: "env-prod.j2"
```

And then use it in your playbook / role `src: "{{ template_name }}"`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I need.